# Laravel - Retrieve only images that belong to the id

Tags: php, html, laravel, upload, data-retrieval

Retrieving all the images from mysql instead it suppose to retrieve only the images that belongs to the form id. Any suggestions?

**Cars Model**

```php
class Cars extends Model
{
    public $table = 'cars';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function carevidence()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarEvidence', 'cars_id', 'id');
    }

}
```

**CarEvidence Model**

```php
class CarEvidence extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'carevidence';

    protected $fillable = [
        'cars_id',
        'car_images',
    ];

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Cars', 'cars_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Store Controller**

```php
if ($post->save()) {
    if ($request->hasFile('carEvidence')) {
        $files = $request->file('carEvidence');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move(public_path('/image'), $filename);

            CarEvidence::create([
                'cars_id' => $post->id,
                'car_images' => $filename
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Retrieve Controller**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $cars = Cars::with('carevidence')->get();

    return view(
        'Validation.validation',
        compact('validations', 'validators', 'departments', 'defects', 'cars')
    );
}
```

**Views for retrieve**

```php
@foreach($cars as $car)
    @foreach($car->carevidence as $evidence)
        <img src="{{ asset('image/'.$evidence->car_images) }}" target="_blank" height="60px" width="60px" />
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Images when retrieve**

[image]

Comment: Doesn't that `edit($id)` function suppose to get only one car instead of all the cars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the first foreach has solved the issue!

```
@foreach($car->carevidence as $evidence)
    <img src="{{ asset('image/'.$evidence->car_images) }}" target="_blank" height="60px" width="60px" />
@endforeach
```